# Add namespace prefix only to child nodes that do not have one

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to add a namespace prefix only to child nodes that do not already have (a different) one, but having a hard time trying to figure out how to exclude them. Right now the existing prefix is just being over-written.

XML:

```
<article article-type="research-article" 
         dtd-version="1.1d3" 
         xml:lang="en" 
         xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"        
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<front>
<article-meta>
<abstract>
<p>
<italic>This</italic> is a 
<mml:math><mml:mi>γ</mml:mi></mml:math> test.
</p>
</abstract>
</article-meta>
</front>
</article>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns="http://www.crossref.org/schema/4.3.6"
                xmlns:jats="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/JATS1"
                xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">

<xsl:template match="*[ancestor-or-self::article/front/article-meta/abstract]" mode="abstract">

    <xsl:element name="jats:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/JATS1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="abstract"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="abstract">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*" mode="abstract">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xref" mode="abstract">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Actual results are:

```
<doi_batch xmlns="http://www.crossref.org/schema/4.3.6" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ai="http://www.crossref.org/AccessIndicators.xsd" xmlns:fr="http://www.crossref.org/fundref.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jats="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/JATS1" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" version="4.3.6" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.crossref.org/schema/4.3.6 http://www.crossref.org/schemas/crossref4.3.6.xsd">
  ...
<jats:abstract xmlns:jats="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/JATS1">
<jats:p>
<jats:italic>This</jats:italic> is a <jats:math><jats:mi>γ</jats:mi></jats:math>test.
</jats:p>
</jats:abstract>
```

But I don't want the `mml:` prefixes to be over-written by the `jats:` one. How can I preserve only those so the output is:

```
<doi_batch xmlns="http://www.crossref.org/schema/4.3.6" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ai="http://www.crossref.org/AccessIndicators.xsd" xmlns:fr="http://www.crossref.org/fundref.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jats="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/JATS1" xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" version="4.3.6" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.crossref.org/schema/4.3.6 http://www.crossref.org/schemas/crossref4.3.6.xsd">

<jats:abstract xmlns:jats="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/JATS1">
<jats:p>
<jats:italic>This</jats:italic> is a <mml:math><mml:mi>γ</mml:mi></mml:math>test.
</jats:p>
</jats:abstract>
```

Comment: You cannot use a prefix without binding to a namespace. Both your input and the output are missing a namespace declaration for the `mml:` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Given a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<abstract xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<p>
<italic>This</italic> is a 
<mml:math><mml:mi>γ</mml:mi></mml:math> test.
</p>
</abstract>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(namespace-uri())]">
    <xsl:element name="jats:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/JATS1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jats:abstract xmlns:jats="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/JATS1">
  <jats:p><jats:italic>This</jats:italic> is a 
<mml:math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mml:mi>γ</mml:mi></mml:math> test.
</jats:p>
</jats:abstract>
```

Comment: I updated my sample XML to provide a bit more clarity on how it appears.